# JPA Query issue expecting EOF, found ')'

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have written a query to fetch data for today's date in JPARepository as below,

```
@Query("SELECT txn FROM Transaction txn WHERE txn.JOB_NAME = :jobName AND TRUNC(txn.EXECUTION_START) = :TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND txn.STATUS = 'RUNNING'")
public Transaction getTransactionByJobName(@Param("jobName") String jobName);
```

But i am getting the below error,

```
line 1:135: unexpected token: (
line 1:136: unexpected token: SYSDATE
line 1:143: expecting EOF, found ')'
```

How to resolve the errors ?

Comment: Should there really be a colon before the second TRUNC and before 'RUNNING'?

Comment: @C.Weber - Thanks..corrected it in the question. But what about the other ERRORS ?

Comment: Mention it as a native query = true

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax issue in the Query.
Below is the corrected Query,

```
@Query("SELECT txn FROM Transaction txn WHERE txn.JOB_NAME = :jobName AND TRUNC(" + " txn.EXECUTION_START ) = TRUNC(" + " :date ) AND txn.STATUS = 'RUNNING'")
public Transaction getTransactionByJobName(@Param("jobName") String jobName, @Param("date") String date);
```